# How to fix sed command to work in groovy

Tags: bash, sed, groovy

I have the following code which works in gitlab (without the `sh` part):

```
sh '''
mkdir ./pylint
docker run --rm --entrypoint=/usr/local/bin/pylint ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_VERSION} --rcfile=.pylintrc --exit-zero ${MODULE} > ./pylint/pylint.log
PYLINT_SCORE=$(sed -n 's/^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*\)\/.*/\1/p' ./pylint/pylint.log)
'''
```

what it does, it takes the value `8.52` from this output: `Your code has been rated at 8.52/10`

I'm trying also to use it in `Jenkinsfile`, but gets the following exception:

```
WorkflowScript: 50: unexpected char: '\' @ line 50, column 75.
   /^Your code has been rated at \([-0-9.]*
```

any idea how to fix it? or use other command from `sed` to get the require output?

Comment: I don't know if this is a sed error, but you could try with sed -r option (extended regex) and another separator in `s///` command: `sed -nr 's@^Your code has been rated at ([-0-9.]*)/.*@\1@p'`

Comment: I got: `PYLINT_SCORE=$'\001'`

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is:

`PYLINT_SCORE=$(sed -n 's#^Your code has been rated at \\([-0-9.]*\\)/.*#\\1#p' ./pylint/pylint.log)`